# Xamarine Shell TitleView Button disappears in iOS

Tags: ios, shell, xamarin, titleview

I'm struggling with this problem.
In my content page i have  a titleview containing a label and a button.
If i execute in android everything works fine but in ios the button disappear out of the right of the screen.

The code:

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Grid
        Margin="0,0,0,0"
        RowDefinitions="auto" 
        ColumnDefinitions="auto,*">
        <Label
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="{Binding Title}"
            TextColor="{StaticResource TextGray}"
            FontSize="Title"
            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center">
        </Label>
        <Grid
            Grid.Column="1"
            BackgroundColor="Green">
            <ImageButton
            Clicked="ShowSearchPage"
            BackgroundColor="red"
            HorizontalOptions="End"
            Source="search"
            ></ImageButton>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

[Result in Android here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzdKI.jpg)

[Result in iOS here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqvO9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code but the testing result is a bit different, the icon is shown incompletely , I even tried to use `StackLayout` instead of the `outer Gird` but no luck , the calulation for the space TitleView occupy is incorrect ,    it is a potential issue , feel free to raise the issue on github : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues.

[image]

And for the temporary workaround , you can set `Margin` on ImageButton , ugly but useful .

```
 <ImageButton Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
```

Comment: Yes, ugly but for now it is the only workaround available, thanks